# How to access and modify a static-served SVG from css / javascript that isn't a part of the DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm using an SVG to draw a custom cursor on my website. I need a special animation to be played on click, and to do that I need to be able to edit properties inside the SVG. Hence the question: Is it possible to do it? How do I query the element and change it?

Neither query selector nor document.findByID worked, because a cursor is not a part of the DOM. Modifying the SVG on the backend isn't a solution as well, because it won't update real-time. I could just fetch an SVG from a static URL, but I can't change it, can I? I have tried multiple ways to do it, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi. Would you please give us more details. I have an idea but I need to know the conditions over which the cursor has to change. Is it on certain types of elements (a `class` of elements for example) or is it other logic?

Comment: @Philippe I have already solved the issue. I define the SVG inside the javascript and then use document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.cursor to access the cursor and set it to the encoded base64 svg that I can now modify freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you utilize SVG as a CSS cursor or as an image source, you won't be able to modify the SVG from your website's JavaScript or CSS because these SVGs are not part of the in-browser DOM.

A possible workaround for this, you might use a pure JavaScript cursor following the mouse position with an SVG inside. You can then manipulate that SVG from the JavaScript as much as you want it.

Ex:

> HTML

```
<div id="customCursorSvg">
    <svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="64px" height="64px">
        <path d="M 4,8 L 4,3 12,11 z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
/* CSS */
#customCursorSvg {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

> JavaScript

```
/* JavaScript */
const cursorSvg = document.getElementById('customCursorSvg');
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    cursorSvg.setAttribute('style',`top: ${e.pageY}px; left: ${e.pageX}px;`);
});

window.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Animation or property change on click
    cursorSvg.firstChild.style.fill = "red";
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That has helped me a lot, but I ended up using a different approach. I define svg inside javascript, then assign it to body.style.cursor. On the mousedown event I modify and reassign the SVG. Works perfectly!